# pum#map#inser_relative(+1) command remap which worked forever recently stopped working

Tags: neovim, autocomplete, pum, inoremap, tab

I have a pum command which does tab autocomplete on a completion list and it recently stopped working and I do not know why. The command...

```
inoremap <silent><expr> <TAB>
\ pum#visible() ? pum#map#insert_relative(+1) :
\ (col('.') <= 1 <Bar><Bar> getline('.')[col('.') - 2] =~# '\s') ?
\ '<TAB>' : ddc#map#manual_complete()
```

started throwing this error:

[image]

Can anyone make sense of that?

Comment: [Please don’t post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/): can you [edit] and put the error text instead of a screenshot? We also need to know where those autoload functions come from.